# Sending emails with celery in Django project

Tags: python, django, email, celery

I can't understand how to send emails with Celery to real people. May be some one can help me? I can send mail to console with 
`EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'` .
But how to configure settings.py file to send email for example to my gmail?
If you have djproject with celery on github I want to see it to understand 
what i have to do.
My github https://github.com/Loctarogar/Django-by-Example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d start with trying to just send an email in Django follow their [sending email](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/) docs which has many examples. Then if you have celery setup, you can write a custom email backend to queue a celery task that sends an email.

Alternatively, you can try out [django-celery-email](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery-email) which will handle most of that for you.